# pandas to_json and read_json with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with index type `Timestamp`.

When I `to_json` the dataframe, the index is converted to something like `'1629849600000'`.

I cannot `pd.to_datetime` this or `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` it.

If I pd.DataFrame the json, it is well formed:

[image]

If I `pd.to_datetime` this, it fails wtih

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the original data?

Comment: @azro Please submit as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` with parameter `unit='ms'`

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.to_datetime(1629417600000, unit='ms'))  # 2021-08-20 00:00:00
```